# mingw32 showing undefined reference to all gtk functions

Tags: c, gcc, gtk, mingw, msys

I am trying to compile the following code, base.c

```
#include <glib/gerror.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h>

int main( int   argc,
          char *argv[] )
{
    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_widget_show  (window);

    gtk_main ();

    return(0);
}
/* example-end */
```

I compile it using

```
gcc -Wall base.c -o base `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

The message I get returned in MinGW is

C:\Users\Sunny\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4eIpLM.o:base.c:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `gtk_init_abi_check`

`collect2: ld return 1 exit status`

I get the same message for `gtk_window_new`, `gtk_widget_show` and `gtk_main`

I have a feeling it could be to do with the following questions:

1) When compiling c programs with gtk where should I have them saved. In the mingw folder somewhere?

2) I current have this appended onto my system variables path: `C:\gtk\bin\;C:\msys\1.0\bin;C:\mingw\bin`
Is it correct?

3) mingw32 can not find the libraries. Is there something I should have done with them when I downloaded msys and mingw

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2010-February/msg00036.html